# Xcode -How To Change App ID Suffix from Old Account To New Account? An app id with identifier is not available. Please enter a different string

Tags: xcode, app-id, bundle-identifier

I'm on Xcode 8.3.3 and my bundle identifier is:

```
com.abc.xyz
```

When I first signed up to create an Apple developer account I used my personal info and registered the above app's bundle id for the App ID Suffix. 
**My Old dev account email is blabla@bla.com**

That was last year, now I registered as a business entity for a developer account and paid the $99 bucks.
**My New dev account email is yadayada@yada.com**

When I try to use the same bundle id for the new account's App ID Suffix I get the error:

> There were errors in the data supplied. Please correct and re-submit.
>   An App ID with Identifier 'com.abc.xyz' is not available. Please enter
>   a different string.

I understand that 2 accounts can't have the same bundle id for the App Id Suffix. The issue is I'm using this bundle id for firebase and other services so it's not that simple to change it. From the app transfer directions [Apple App Transfer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html) it seems I also would have had to had the app in the App Store:

`The App must have had at least one version that has been released to the App Store`.

It says if I delete the app I can't use the bundle id:

```
Important:  If you delete your app, you can’t restore it. The SKU or app name can’t be reused in the same organization. If you’ve uploaded a build, your bundle ID can’t be reused.
```

How can I either transfer my my bundle id from my old personal account (which I'm no longer paying for) to my new account which I am paying for?

How can I delete the App ID Suffix from my old account?

In either case I still have access to both accounts and I need my new account to use the same bundle id `com.abc.xyz` that was under my old account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just called Apple (800) 633-2152. Luckily on my old account the 1 yr membership had expired and I never renewed it so it automatically switched me over to a free account. The rep was able to delete the bundle id in the old account because it became a free account. I think if it was a paid account I would've been sol because she said "I was only able to delete it because you was under the free program".

Once she deleted it she sat on the phone with me and I was able to use the bundle id as the Apple ID Suffix on my new account.

If your like me and you have 2 accounts and you want to switch the bundle id from 1 account to the other you can definitely call and they'll do it if the first account is under a free plan. Otherwise your probably going to have to ask them to cancel it or wait until it expires.